# PHP function stops working after checking returned array TRUE or FALSE

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have small problem with function that grabs all products from the same category, with limit to 5 products only. Some categories have more than 5 and some only 1 or 2 products.

The problem I am facing with this function is, it works only when category contains more than 5 products and what I need it to do is to work when category contains at least 2 products with keeping limit to maximum 5 products.

I do not understand what went wrong with this function, the only thing that I added was the `if` statement that should check if something is returned at all and if `TRUE` then it should follow with the rest of my logic.

```
function additional_products($db, $current, $pid, $image_path){
    $res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM files WHERE parentpageID = :current AND pageID = '0' AND show_in_category = '1' AND cat_page_pos = '1' AND ID <> :id LIMIT 5");
    $res->execute(array(':current' => $current, ':id' => $pid));
    if($res -> fetch() != 0){
    print<<<END
<div  class="related_pr">
<h3>Related Templates</h3>
<ul>\n
END;
    while ($info = $res -> fetch()){
        $rel_template = '<li><a href="'.SITE_DOMAIN.DS.$info['ImagePath'].DS.$info['referring_url'].'">';
        $rel_template .= $info['templateTitle'];
        $rel_template .= '<img src="'.$image_path.$info['ImagePath'].DS.$info['templateImage'].'" alt="'.$info['templateTitle'].'" title="'.$info['templateTitle'].'" width="'.$info['templimgwidth'].'" height="'.$info['templimgheight'].'">';
        $rel_template .= '</a></li>'."\n";
    print<<<END
    $rel_template
END;
    }
print<<<END
</ul>
</div>\n
END;
}else{
        return side_nav($db, $current);
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: remove the spaces from `$res -> fetch()` like: `$res->fetch()`

Comment: @Hardy Nothing has changed after removing spaces

Comment: Are you using mysqli?

Comment: @Hardy That's correct syntax

Comment: What's the definition of fetch then? What extension are you using to access MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL directly on your mysql server to check how many rows the query actually returns?

Comment: @jreuab I am using PDO

Comment: @MrZebra, I did, in fact I have done 'print_r($res -> fetch())' before if statement and it returned array for 1 product, which it was meant to do since category I was on contained only 1 product.

Comment: What it does is, it prints everything that is inside PRINT<<<END, but does not run my while loop, if I remove the if statement completely than everything is working, but I have no way to replacing an empty array with something elese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `fetch()` in the `if` statement, it's fetching the first row. So when you call it again in the `while` loop, that starts from the *second* row.

Instead, use `$rows = $res->fetchAll()` to get all the results at once, then you can test `if(!empty($rows))`. Then use `foreach($rows as $info)` in place of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this:

```
if($res -> fetch() != 0)
```

This does not only check if there are any (more) records in your database result set, but also moves on to the next row. Your first row will be truncated. Use `PDOStatement::rowCount` to find out how many rows your query retrieved.

I don't know if this is your only problem because your question was a bit unclear.

Also your code is a mess.

Comment: `rowCount()` isn't guaranteed to work for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I didn't knew that. As he is using MySQL that shouldn't be a problem though.